# Redirect (or show the node) taxonomy term page to node, if there's only one node associated with that term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, hooks, redirection

So I'd like to redirect taxonomy term page or show the full content of the node on taxonomy page if there's only one node associated with that term.

Comment: Hey Sohail,I come back stackexchange ,again see you with hard questions boy :D . hard question need bounty :D

Comment: Welcome back bro! :D I'll give you 500 bounty since you just asked :D

Comment: Tnx Dear, your questions often are particular  that need exclusive answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is handle it in `hook_preprocess_page`(maybe there is another or better solutions but this is good too)

put this in `template.php`

**first solution(maybe not worked)**

```
function YOURTEMPLATE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    $tid = arg(2);
    $items = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid;
    if(count($item)==1){
         drupal_goto('node/'.$items[0]->nid);
     }
    }
}
```

**Alternative solution**

```
function YOURTEMPLATE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    $tid = arg(2);
    $items = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);
    if(count($items)==1){

         //another solution is set a variable in preprocess and in page.tpl.php or your taxonomy tempalte page redirect it 
         $variables['soheil_redirect_tax'] = array('path' => url('node/'.$items['nid']));

    }
  }
```

**if first solution (drupal_goto) not worked in page.tpl.php or your custom template for terms page handle redirect**(I mean in `page.tpl.php` file or `taxonomy--term.tpl.php` file) with

```
 if(isset($soheil_redirect_tax)){
    drupal_goto($soheil_redirect_tax['path']);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yusof, I'll take a look into your solution and let you know

Comment: @Sohail You're welcome,Ok ;)

Comment: Hey Yusef, it almost worked with the second approach, it does redirect when there's only 1 taxonomy term on the page, but on my localhost it redirects to `~sohail/helger/~sohail/helger/node/`, as you can see it repeats the base url and does not load the `nid` of the node to redirect it to

Comment: @Sohail try to `dsm($items)` to see what you have there,maybe its a array then you have to replace it with `$items[0]['nid']`.

Comment: it still doesn't work with `$items[0]['nid']` , and unfortunately `dsm($items)` is empty, I wonder if we can access nodes associated with terms like this

Comment: Thank you so much Yusef I ended up replacing it with `$items['0']` since it's the very first node associated to that `tid` , well done.
while we are at it, is there anyway to actually redirect to the path alias and not straight to node/nid ?

Comment: @Sohail you're welocm,e use drupal_get_path_alias to get path alias.